# Odoo - Adding Font Module

Tags: python, sass, module, fonts, odoo

I need to add a custom font to the Odoo website editor, so I followed this [tutorial](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-odoo-16)

I created the custom module, but when I started my local Odoo server (nginx) the navigator interface showed me this:

[image: Connection Lost. Trying to reconnect]

I can't access the Odoo interface unless I remove the custom font module...

The server console showed me this error several times:

```
odoo        |   File "<unknown>", line 1
odoo        |     'assets': {
odoo        |             ^
odoo        | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried creating other custom modules in the same folder and they worked just fine *(as long as I removed the custom font module in question)*

I really appreciate any help you can provide :^}

I uploaded my module to this [repository](https://github.com/ezert/glacial_indifference_font)

Odoo version: 17